# “Unable to connect to gear” in scaled openshift app

Tags: openshift

I'm having php-5.4 scaled app with mysql-5.5. Since it's scaled app mysql is placed on separate gear than app instances.
Since around 03/08/2015 I'm unable to connect to mysql gear, nor my application. I've been trying the following:

Restart all apps and deps with ctl_all.

```
$ rhc ssh --gears -a loot ctl_all restart
Unable to connect to gear 556c74555973caffa300022c@556c74555973caffa300022c-honourforever.rhcloud.com
(...)
```

SSH connection to mysql gear.

```
$ ssh -vvv 556c74555973caffa300022c@556c74555973caffa300022c-honourforever.rhcloud.com
    OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 556c74555973caffa300022c-honourforever.rhcloud.com [54.166.94.12] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 54.166.94.12 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
    ssh: connect to host 556c74555973caffa300022c-honourforever.rhcloud.com port 22: Bad file number
```

Check gear storage used percentage.

```
    $ rhc show-app loot --gear quota 
    Unable to connect to gear
    556c74555973caffa300022c@556c74555973caffa300022c-honourforever.rhcloud.com
    Gear                     Cartridges           Used Limit
    ------------------------ ------------------- ----- ----- 
    556b44544382ec7b32000050 haproxy-1.4 php-5.4 92 MB  1 GB
    556c74555973caffa300022c mysql-5.5           error  1 GB
```

Therefore I have no means at the moment to connect to mysql or gear it's sitting on.

Comment: This looks like a problem you should be reporting to OpenShift support. This isn't a programming question.

Comment: I'm also having this error! Are you able to resolve it? can you please share what you have done. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunetlly I've not managed to get thru the issue. I had back-up of database so I just wiped everything and restored database from back-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a programming problem and cannot be fixed from user side. To fix this problem it is needed to contact OpenShift support.